# in Shell, How to do arithmetic operation on a number which is part of a string?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sh

I wanted to add 100 to the insertions, tried below, but it is adding $1 to it instead ?

```
#!/bin/bash
change_summary="17 files changed, 441 insertions(+), 49 deletions(-)"
lines_added="100"
echo $change_summary
echo $change_summary | awk '{ print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4+$lines_added " " $5 " " $6 " " $7}'
```

it prints

```
17 files changed, 441 insertions(+), 49 deletions(-)
17 files changed, 458 insertions(+), 49 deletions(-)
```

I am expecting it to print 541 insertions.

is there a better way to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an awk variable (tested with GNU awk):

```
 awk -v l=$lines_added '{ print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4+l " " $5 " " $6 " " $7}'
```

or even more succinctly:

```
 $ echo $change_summary | awk -v l=$lines_added '{ $4 += l; print}'
 17 files changed, 541 insertions(+), 49 deletions(-)
```

Comment: thanks, I am using your second command, I also need to add number to $6, I tried `echo $change_summary | awk -v l=$lines_added  d=$lines_deleted '{ $4 += l $6 +=d; print}'` it throws error, obviously I am making some mistake. any help? thanks a lot.

Comment: @Krish You need to use `-v` for each variable: `awk -v a=x -v b=y ...` and semicolons between each `$x += y` statement.

Comment: Nice! Note saying `print $1 " " $2`, etc is a bit unnecessary. Just say `print $1, $2` since the default output field separator is the space.

Answer (score 0):

You should "unquote" the `$lines_added`:

```
~$ echo $change_summary | awk '{ print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " ($4)+'$lines_added' " " $5 " " $6 " " $7}'
`17 files changed, 541 insertions(+), 49 deletions(-)
```

Since it's a bash variable, not a awk one.

Comment: great, thanks, is there a better way to do this? or what I am doing is fine?

Comment: I don't think there is a right way, but as @Jens pointed out, you can pass variable through the -v option